# Anchor's reverting to the top in HTML

Tags: html, anchor

I've got a page that links to an anchor:

```
<a name="1"></a>
```

with the link

```
<a href="examplepage.htm#1">Link</a>.
```

When I click on that link within the page the anchor's sitting on, it works as expected. But when I click on that link from another page, it loads the page at the point of the anchor as expected, but then reverts to the top of the page after a fraction of second.

No clue why, and all my research is fogged up by tutorials on how to link to the top of the page, the opposite of what I want to do!

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks, Oli.

Comment: It should work just as expected. Any Javascript involved?

Comment: No, none, but it is on an APSX page, will that make a difference?

Comment: Please post the URL of a page (the linking page) where this happens, identify which link you are referring to, and specify on which browser(s) you observed the phenomenon.

Comment: http://www.bishopfleming.co.uk/SpecialPages/Corporate-Finance.aspx - works on Firefox and Safari, but not on IE or Chrome. It's the three mini menus in blue boxes that aren't working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `scroll()` in the `onload` function!

```
<body class="LTR Safari Chrome Safari18 Chrome18 ENUS ContentBody" onload="scroll()">
```

Comment: Ahhhhh... that may be some unavoidable text from my CMS. I'll look into it, thanks.

Comment: Yep, that's sorted it out *facepalms self*